# vim settings in erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

how can i apply vim settings to erb file?? like

```
/* tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 foldmethod=indent */
```

seems like

```
<% # xxx %>
# xxxx
<!-- xxx -->
```

didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (put it close to the top of the file):

```
<!-- vim: tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 foldmethod=indent
-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the `vim:` modeline prefix.  From `:h modeline`.

There are two forms of modelines.  The first form:

```
[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}
```

The second form (compatible with some versions of Vi):

```
[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]
```